# Run Application Command to open Terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Question: What command do you type in to the "Run Application" box on ubuntu to open the terminal?

---

Info:
I'm having horrible horrible driver issues on my netbook. I might be able to solve some of these problems if I could just get to Terminal, but all I have is my keyboard, no mouse, so i need to know what command to type in to run application (Which I can get to with alt-f2) to open terminal.

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The command you are looking for is:

```
gnome-terminal
```

You can also run `bash`, selecting "run in terminal"

Comment: Ah yes, just never thought to guess tacking "gnome" to the command. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to use hotkey: CRTL+ALT+T